# Some site are not accessible while using two different gateways

Tags: router, dns, website

I've configured a network with two routers & one switch. Both the routers are the internet gateways & I've disabled DHCP because of the domain controller that I've connected to the switch. Therefore, whenever I hook up a client to the switch, domain controller issues the IP as I've configured AD, DHCP & DNS in it. I've also declared the server that the default gateway is only one router but not both. So, that the management people can use the other router by configuring the gateway manually.

Now my problem is that when I configure the gateway of that router, internet works but some sites aren't accessible.. Can this be due to any restriction applies in the domain controller..

Answer (score 0):

It might be because DNS cache on DNS controller or stations.
Try to flush DNS cache.

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

If it helps. If yes - it's only temporary.
I suggest you to use policy routing when simultaneously two active gateways used in single network and you have to push requests from specific users, to specific sites, through desired gateway. this technic called [ECMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-cost_multi-path_routing), with further mangle configuration.

Comment: I actually didn't try the flushdns command.. anyways I'll try that and if it didn't help.. I'll also try the other one you mentioned.. thanks